# Align text vertically center in Flexbox in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to align text vertically inside flex container.I used following codes with aligncontent , justifycontent etc like below.

```
<Col
            size={1}
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignContent: "center",
              backgroundColor: "orange",

              borderRightColor: "#373738",
              borderWidth: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: "red",
                fontSize: 14,
                alignItems: "center",
                textAlign: "center",

                color: "#fff",
              }}
            >
              {ago}
            </Text>
          </Col>
```

But none of them works , Please look below. Still the text is not aligned center vertically.

[image]

Comment: No , did not work.

Comment: If you're using a custom font, it might be because of the vertical padding of the font, like [poppins](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/241). Adding `includeFontPadding: false` https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#includefontpadding-android solves this problem. Also, sorry my previous comment should be `textAlignVertical: 'center'`

Comment: Yea , I tried that before , still not working.

Comment: Can your create a example? Trying your code on [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@truetiem/center-text) works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try setting style in Text to be
`display: flex;`
`align-items: center;`
`height: 100%;`

Comment: https://codepen.io/Svarog1389/pen/MWmrbzg

See this pen, I tried to recreate your example minimally. Try removing unnecessary css properties from your parent div. For example, justifyContent and alignContent don't do anything if the component doesn't have `display: flex` inside it, and `flex: 1` only works in children of the component that has `display: flex`.